# Multiple Modals with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I´m building some modals for fun but I can´t make it work for multiple modals.

**useModal** hook

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const useModal = () => {

    const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsShowing(!isShowing);
    }

    return {
        isShowing,
        toggle,
    }
};

export default useModal;
```

**Modal** component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Modal = (props) => {

    const { toggle, isShowing, children } = props;

    useEffect(() => {

        const handleEsc = (event) => {
            if (event.key === 'Escape') {
                toggle()
            }
        };

        if (isShowing) {    
            window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);
        }

        return () => window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEsc);

    }, [isShowing, toggle]);

    if (!isShowing) {
        return null;
    }

    return (
        <div className="modal">
            <button onClick={ toggle } >close</button>
            { children }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

in my **Main** component

If I do this the only modal in the page works fine

```
const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();
...
<Modal isShowing={ isShowing } toggle={ toggle }>first modal</Modal>
```

but when I try to add another one it doesn´t work. it doesn´t open any modal

```
const { isShowingModal1, toggleModal1 } = useModal();
const { isShowingModal2, toggleModal2 } = useModal();
...
<Modal isShowing={ isShowingModal1 } toggle={ toggleModal1 }>first modal</Modal>
<Modal isShowing={ isShowingModal2 } toggle={ toggleModal2 }>second modal</Modal>
```

what I´m doing wrong? thank you

if you want to check it out please go to https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cannon-guptw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: How can we guess what "doesn't work" means, please make a sandbox too, https://codesandbox.io/ with a minimal example

Comment: you are right sorry about that. here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cannon-guptw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try that:

```
const useModal = () => {
  const [isShowing, setIsShowing] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => {
    setIsShowing(!isShowing);
  };

  return [isShowing, toggle];
};
```

then:

```
export default function App() {
  const [isShowing, toggle] = useModal();
  const [isShowingModal1, toggleModal1] = useModal();
  const [isShowingModal2, toggleModal2] = useModal();
```

Comment: perfect!!  this is beautiful. I would have to read the difference between [] and {} in hooks thank you so much

Comment: Well It is got nothing to do with hooks, It's pure es6 JS.

Comment: In your example isShowingModal1, toggleModal1 and isShowingModal2, toggleModal2 were undefined because they don't exist on the returned hook object. While in destructuring array you can name every array item in any name

Answer (score -6):

if you have multiple modal then dynamically inject `<div>` inside the page body and map modal to it.
to create div use,

```
    var divTag = document.createElement("div");
    divTag.setAttribute('id', 'modal');
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(divTag);
    document.getElementById('modal').innerHTML = modalHtML;
```

This should work.